# Removing duplicates using LINQ returns "Error removing duplicates: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'."

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable

I am using the following function to remove all the duplicate values of a certain field called `keyField` in a `DataTable`.

```
public DataTable RemoveDuplicates(DataTable dt, string keyField)
{
    IEnumerable<DataRow> uniqueContacts = dt.AsEnumerable()
                            .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>(keyField))
                            .Select(g => g.First());
    DataTable dtOut = uniqueContacts.CopyToDataTable();
    return dtOut;
}
```

However, when the data type of the `keyField` is an `Int32` this will produce the following Exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.

How can I remove the duplicate values even though the `keyField` is not of type `string`?

Comment: Do you know the data type when calling this method?

Comment: Exactly! But I doubt it would be anything other than varchar or integer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make your method generic:

```
public DataTable RemoveDuplicates<T>(DataTable dt, string keyField)
{
    IEnumerable<DataRow> uniqueContacts = dt.AsEnumerable()
                        .GroupBy(x => x.Field<T>(keyField))
                        .Select(g => g.First());
    DataTable dtOut = uniqueContacts.CopyToDataTable();
    return dtOut;
}
```

Then call it specifying the column type

```
RemoveDuplicates<int>(dt, "id");
```

If you don't know the type the other option is to use indexer of `DataRow` instead of `Field` method:

```
public DataTable RemoveDuplicates(DataTable dt, string keyField)
{
    IEnumerable<DataRow> uniqueContacts = dt.AsEnumerable()
                        .GroupBy(x => x[keyField].ToString())
                        .Select(g => g.First());
    DataTable dtOut = uniqueContacts.CopyToDataTable();
    return dtOut;
}
```